# jQuery function creates loop

Tags: jquery, loops, colorbox

In the design below:

```
<div class="hero">

    <div class="niro">
        <div class="piro"> My </div>
        <div class="piro"> Awesome </div>
        <div class="piro"> List </div>
    </div>

    <div class="zero">
        <a href="#" class="colorbox-load"> Clicking here pops up ColorBox </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

In jQuery, I want to wrap all the `piro` class, so, I did something like

```
$('.piro').wrapAll('<div class="piro-extended"> </div>');
```

When the page loads for the first time, The code of the output is:

```
<div class="hero">

    <div class="niro">
        <div class="piro-extended">
            <div class="piro"> My </div>
            <div class="piro"> Awesome </div>
            <div class="piro"> List </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="zero">
        <a href="#" class="colorbox-load"> Clicking here pops up ColorBox </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

But when I click the colorbox link and after closing the modal, the code of same page results in `wrapAll()` loop like:

```
<div class="hero">

    <div class="niro">
        <div class="piro-extended">
            <div class="piro-extended">
                <div class="piro-extended">
                    <div class="piro"> My </div>
                    <div class="piro"> Awesome </div>
                    <div class="piro"> List </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="zero">
        <a href="#" class="colorbox-load"> Clicking here pops up ColorBox </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I get rid of this loop ?

Comment: Try `$(document).ready(function(){$('.niro').children().wrapAll('<div class="piro-extended"> </div>');});`

Comment: More information is needed http://jsfiddle.net/yzT8n/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about add a condition?

```
if($('.piro-extended').length == 0) {
    $('.piro').wrapAll('<div class="piro-extended"> </div>');
}
```

Comment: thank you man.... it was eating my brain.... I did test first like if `$(.piro).closest().length === 0` then only `wrapAll()`, but it wasn't working. May be my logic was wrong, I was trying to check the parent, but checking directly with __classname__ was perfect solution. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

Use **[unwrap()](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/)**

```
   $(".colorbox-load").click(function(){
     $('.piro-extended').unwrap();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.piro').wrapAll('<div class="piro-extended" />');
```